# Check if user exists using CoreData before loading the first screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, appdelegate

I have made an iOS 7 app using Xcode5. The app includes CoreData. I want to check if a user exists before the first screen is loading. The first screen is dependent on the the user in the database. If a user exists, the dashboard screen will be loaded. If the user doesn't exist, the login screen will be loaded.

I check if the user exists in the viewDidAppear method of the loginView, but I guess that it is not necessary to load this view first, because of most of time I don't even need the loginView.

Comment: A initial VC (with your splashscreen as background for example, or a small loading animation) at start, checking what should be launched after could do the trick...

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I had not thought of that ;)

Comment: you can check if the user exists in the AppDelegate before you present the first view controller. Than you can decide which view controller to show based on the outcome of the check